# Adding "0" to front of all values in column using ArcGIS Field Calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, field-calculator, leading-zero

In ArcInfo 10.1 I have a table for each state with Zip Code values. The 5-digit Zip Codes that start with "0" have been reduced to 4-digits. I cannot figure out how to add a "0" to the front of all the values in the table. Tried a number of field-calculations but just can't seem to get it right.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I know, if you are storing zip codes in a numerical field (integer, float, etc.) it will always strip the preceding zero.  The only way I have found to deal with this is to store zip codes in a text column instead.

Answer (score 13):

As [Brian mentioned](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/61526/115) you will need to store the data in a text field. Then the field calculation  is: 
right("00000" + [Existing_ZIP_CODE_FIELD],5)

this will ensure you have all of the necessary leading 0s up to 5 characters.

Comment: Another way to add leading zeroes is using the [`zfill` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill) on a string: `str(2451).zfill(5)` will result in `"02451"`.

Comment: And if you want Python code instead of VB Script, use `!Existing_ZIP_CODE_FIELD!.zfill(5)` if existing field is already a string, or `"{:05d}".format(!Existing_ZIP_CODE_FIELD!)` if it's an integer.

Comment: Another thing that tripped me up when I was doing this is that you need to check the "start editing" box next to the Run button in order for it to work.

Answer (score 2):

As [@Brian has said](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/61526/115), the field will have to be text to keep the zero on the left.  Here's a quick, basic python example:

```
import arcpy

#add path to shapefile, feature class
fc = "..."

arcpy.AddField_management(fc, "ZIP5", "TEXT", "", "", 5)

rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc)
for row in rows:
    #row.ZIP4 should be changed to the field
    #with your ZIP, ex: row.ZIP_CODE
    new_value = str(row.ZIP4)[:5].rjust(5,"0")
    row.ZIP5_2 = new_value
    rows.updateRow(row)
del row
del rows
```

This makes use of [UpdateCursor](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v0000003m000000), [Add Field (Data Management)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000047000000), and Python string formatting, particularly [.rjust()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_rjust.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I think [How To: Keep leading zeros for zip codes in ArcGIS attribute tables](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/36082) has the information you needed about how to keep leading zeros for zip code field.

> Zip codes are exclusively numbers, and are often stored in a numeric
>   (formatted) field. When a zip code with leading zeros is entered in a
>   numeric field, the leading zeros are omitted, therefore creating an
>   incorrect zip code. ArcMap tries to match the data type with the
>   appropriate field types for imported tables, often causing zip codes
>   to be designated to a numeric field.

Answer (score 1):

Using python not the field calc but still works.

Used for dynamically adding leading zeros to a field based on the desired number of leading zeros and the length of the string with basic error handling

For example:

- 2    = 00002
- 89   = 00089
- 187  = 00187
- 2098 = 02098

Note the field must be Text otherwise there is no point into running this.

Run in ArcMap

```
fc_name = 'NAME'
fields = ["FIELD_NAME"]

desired_length = 5

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc_name, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0].isdigit():
            if len(row[0]) < desired_length:

                row[0] = row[0].zfill(desired_length)
                print row
                cursor.updateRow(row)

            elif len(row[0]) > desired_length:
                print ("> Lenght - Manually Check: " + row[0])
        else:
            print ("NAN - Manually Check: " + row[0])

print ("Finished")
```

Answer (score -1):

use & instead of + for this to work in VBA right("00"& [CID],2)